# Why does type conversion fail at compile time?

Tags: go

Consider the following code snippet:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Interface interface {
    Fun()
}

type Int int

func (Int) Fun() {}

func main() {
    var x interface{}
    x = Int(42)
    if _, ok := x.(int); !ok {
        fmt.Println("type assertion fails")
    }

    // why do the lines below fail to compile?  
    var y Interface
    y = Int(42)
    if _, ok := y.(int); !ok {
        fmt.Println("type assertion fails")
    }
}
```

The first type assertion is performed as expected. However, in the second case, the type assertion is performed at compile time (in other words, the program doesn't compile)

> impossible type assertion:
>       int does not implement Interface (missing Fun method)

My understanding from reading "The Go programming language" (page 206) is that the second snippet should compile, and the type conversion should fail at run time.

**Is there any difference between the 2 snippets; aren't both `x` and `y` of interface type (different interfaces)? And why second fails at compile time?**

Coming from a C++ background, this looks very much like combining `static_assert` (compile time) and `assert` (run time) into a single type assertion, which looks a bit odd.

Comment: `int` values are assignable to `interface{]` type; `int` values are not assignable to `Interface` type. Presumably a compiler helps you realise your condition is never to be met, since that type assertion makes no sense from the Go's type system perspective.

Comment: @zerkms I just don't understand why it doesn't compile. From a language perspective, it looks like there's no fundamental difference between the 2 snippets. I agree that the compiler is probably smart and catches the type mismatch, but is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. What is your question?

Comment: @Flimzy "Is there any subtle difference between the 2 snippets? ... And why second fails at compile time?" I'm asking about the language rules, there's a big difference between compile-time errors and runtime errors.

Comment: @Flimzy Ok, I clearly understand the error message. From reading the Go book, I didn't know that if the compiler can do the type assertion at compile time, it'll do it (which is what happens here) and won't compile. It's very much like combining `static_assert` (compile time) and `assert` (run time) from C++ into a single type assertion, which confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the spec:

> More precisely, if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must implement the (interface) type of x; otherwise the type assertion is invalid since it is not possible for x to store a value of type T. If T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x implements the interface T.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

So it's expected it fails to compile, since `int` is not an interface type; and it does not implement the `x` (`Interface`).

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense, and indeed the compiler can be sure that `y` will never implement `Interface`, since it's of a fundamental type `int`.